# What is the intuition behind the generalized confidence interval?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, intuition

What is the intuition behind the generalized confidence interval? My best description on GCI that it is the way to derive a formula to calcuate the area of the center region in a asymetry distribution where it has the two-sided-equal-tailed regions in which the area of the two-sided-equal-tailed regions are the same in the n dimensional case.

A paper on the GCI: http://www.stat.colostate.edu/statresearch/stattechreports/Technical%20Reports/2002/02_10.pdf

Also: http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/a10n420.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "We can never know the true proportion in a population, and we can
>   only know the proportion within our sample. The Central Limit Theorem
>   suggests that we are much more likely to get a value close to the true
>   population value from our sample value because the distribution of
>   sample proportions will follow a normal distribution. Weird samples
>   are less probable than representative samples. The degree to which
>   your sample proportion will differ from the population proportion will
>   depend on the variation in the population and the size of the sample.
>
> The Central Limit Theorem allows us to say that the average
>   (proportion) of the sample follows a normal distribution centered on
>   the true population average with standard deviation  where sigma is
>   the standard deviation of the population and $n$ is the size of the
>   sample.
>
> To increase accuracy, you can take a larger sample, but there are
>   diminishing returns to  increasing sample size because we are taking
>   its square root. The more diversity there is in the population, the
>   less accurate your sample proportion will be. You determine the size
>   of your sample based on your resources and desired accuracy. Most
>   polls are in the ballpark of $n=1,000$."

Quoted from: [Confidence Intervals and Hypothesis Testing](http://dss.ucsd.edu/~jsettle/poli30_section/Handout%20and%20Clarifications_v2.pdf)

Also,

> "A confidence interval is a range of values that we hope includes the
>   true population value, for now that is the population mean.  We might
>   think of it as an interval of guesses of the values of the population
>   mean.  The interval is based on the information we randomly select
>   from the population and include in the sample.  The size of this
>   interval depends on the confidence that we want to have that the
>   interval includes the population mean, the size of the sample we
>   select, and the standard deviation of dispersion of the population
>   values (usually we estimate this standard deviation with the standard
>   deviation of the sample of values we have collected)."

Quoted from: [Further Expositions on Intuition and Confidence Intervals](http://paws.wcu.edu/jarrell/hointuitchangesII.htm)

Comment: The question is about *generalized* confidence intervals, not CI in the usual sense.